# Андроид студия не реагирует на клавиатуру

Tags: android-studio

Всем привет. Поставил Андроид студию на мак. Открываю проект, а написать ничего не могу, клавиатура при нажатии издает звук, а символы не печатает и не удаляет. Это первый мак, подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Может оно в режиме только для чтения открыло?

Comment: А как исправить?

Comment: Снять признак для чтения (это в finder) или разобраться, почему оно так сделало. Может Вы с флешки открыли, которая некорректно вытянута или ещё что то